# Links missing in AngularJS 2 website in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I see all the links (live example) missing from https://angular.io website when I view the website in IE 9. Example shown below.

Is it just me seeing this issue or it's happening for everyone with IE?

Is it a bug in website or Angularjs 2 doesn't support IE 9 completely?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft probably fixed that bug in a later release of IE.  I've had issues with visual updates on IE 9-10 but more in IE9.  The Microsoft support path is to ask all users to move to Edge or at least IE11 as soon as possible.  More importantly why would anyone risk using those older browsers.  Please read...
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.